# Snowflake with Terraform - S3 external table with INFER_SCHEMA

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

With Terraform, I have created a snowflake_external_table for data residing on S3 bucket.
I use "column" attribute to specify the columns of parquet file on S3 bucket.

There is an option in Snowflake where we can infer schema from the files rather than defining the column list for external table.

In snowflake it will be -

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mytable
  USING TEMPLATE (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*))
      FROM TABLE(
        INFER_SCHEMA(
          LOCATION=>'@mystage',
          FILE_FORMAT=>'my_parquet_format'
        )
      )
    )
    LOCATION=@mystage
    FILE_FORMAT=my_parquet_format
    AUTO_REFRESH=false;
```

I could not find any option to have INFER_SCHEMA in https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Snowflake-Labs/snowflake/latest/docs/resources/external_table#nestedblock--column - terraform documentation for this.

Am I missing something or can you please guide on it?

Comment: I'm guessing that the Terraform Snowflake provider doesn't support it (yet)